# Are lists really necessary? Are there benefits?

Tags: html

Is there any benefit to using an ordered list versus just typing out the number and item? It just seems like a waste of time (considering it takes more time to type the tags for each item). When should and shouldn't I use an ordered/unordered list?

Comment: Adding new items - can be automatically numbered with an ordered list.  Styling the list is much easier if each item is in a separate container.

Comment: Google 'semantic HTML'

Comment: There's a *HUGE* difference.  If your content is logically, a "numbered list", then you should *always* represent it in HTML with `<ol>`.  SUGGESTION: As Kevin Boucher suggested, please look up [Semantic HTML](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/semantic-html/)

Answer (score 1):

Well in most cases you are correct you can use a normal method, however if organization is something you are concerned with then having a list will help you much more. For example, you are able to modify your lists much easier then you would if you had to modify each individual segment of manually typed out information.